# Pyramid with asterisks: extra whitespace

Tags: python

My code currently is:

```
s = int(raw_input("Enter width: "))
i=0
y=0
while i < (s+1):
        if i != 0:
                print(" "*((s)-y))+(i*'* ') + (" "*((s)-y))
        i += 1
        y += 1
```

I am attempting to submit this code to a challenge website and they are saying that the code is wrong as it does not meet up to their requirements.

This is the error message that they are stating:

[image]

Can you guys please help me :) ?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you post what the requirements actually are?  You might not have whitespace where they want it or something (It looks like they don't want you to have the trailing whitespace) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the error message from the website, it looks like they don't want you to have the trailing whitespace, although that's pretty hard to tell.  You can test that easily by:

```
print(" "*((s)-y))+(i*'* ') + (" "*((s)-y))
```

to

```
print(" "*((s)-y))+(i*'* ').rstrip())
```

or

```
print(" "*((s)-y))+(i*'* ')[:-1])
```

Comment: I first thought of the `rstrip` approach too. `(" "*(s-y) + " ".join("*"*i))` should work as well.

Comment: @DSM -- interesting usage of `join`.  Any reason to prefer it over `rstrip()` (or slicing for that matter?)

Comment: Only in the sense that it doesn't build anything it throws away and so has a certain elegance.  It's actually a little slower.

Comment: @DSM -- `'*'*i` builds a string which gets thrown away after the `join` completes ... (which is why it doesn't surprise me that it's slower)

Comment: Heh.  You've got me there (and since strings are immutable the addition throws away stuff too).  I guess I meant that the final string is purely the sum of constructed substrings, and every constructed substring is used in the final string.  It's irrelevant-squared here, of course, but it's a habit..

Comment: @DSM -- http://pokit.org/get/img/ab7091e4467a1a282c1665978dc6cda9.jpg
Thank you so much.